# Error when trying to use drawer for react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View

} from "react-native";

//library imports
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen'
import SettingsScreen from './SettingsScreen'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyApp />
    );
      }
}

const MyApp = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen
  }
})
export default App;
styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
})
```

The above is my main program. I have two more programs for Home screen and the Settings screen.
I'm following through this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJmsmrRtMyw). At 3.09, I try to load the app, but it comes up with an error:

> Invariant Violation: Module Appregistry is not a registered callable module (callingrunApplication).

I just started learning React Native 3 days ago and I would really appreciate you answers.

Comment: What is version react-native do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop your app and do this

```
npm start --reset-cache
```

Hope this helps!